# How do I add Action to subfolders of a specific folder in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

While creating a Netbeans plugin, I'm using:

```
    @ActionReference(path = "Loaders/folder/any/Actions")
```

This is to add an action to folders in Netbeans but this is adding an action to all folders. How can I add the Action to subfolders of a specific folder in NetBeans?